# How to convert yyyymm to yyyy-mm-dd in sql?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a date 202003 (yyyymm) and i want to convert to 2020-03-01 using sql.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `to_date()`.  I think this works:

```
to_date(yyyymm, 'YYYYMM')
```

But to be safe, you might use:

```
to_date(yyyymm || '01', 'YYYYMMDD')
```

This should return a date, which seems sufficient.  If you want a particular string representation:

```
to_char(to_date(yyyymm, 'YYYYMM'), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code gives desired output.

```
select to_date('202003', 'YYYYMM') date;
```

For more information please refer below link

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_date.html